# Capturing further detail in agile

Tags: agile

Couple of questions about capturing detail in an agile project.

I understand the concept that user stories are not there to capture detail in the first instance but are a placeholder for more detailed conversations with the users.  Where should the detail from such conversations be recorded - in the user story, as a use case or scenarios (or something else)?

Specifically we have a requirement to interface with 'system X'. As a result of detailed analysis I want to record how the interaction of the browser with system X for example:

- What triggers the sending of details to system X interface
- The data sent to system X
- the handling of responses from system X
- what happens if system X is not available

and so on.  In waterfall this would be captured in a use case - in the agile world where do I record this detail?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The typical/old school system is "write them on the back of the card", but in reality you have to consider that said information is fundamentally *transient*. It is basically only notes for the developer that is going to implement the story.

Citing the [agile manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/)

> Working software over comprehensive documentation

and

> Working software is the primary measure of progress.

In other words, ultimately the requirements are documented in *working software*. This is to answer to the first part of your question.

In the second part, you mention, basically, documenting an existing system. In that case, I am not sure what the value of doing so is (I don't doubt that it is valuable, but I am not sure on how you plan to use it).

In any case: ask your team and let them self-organize. Do they want to store this kind of information in a wiki? A google doc? Let them choose.

From the point of view of agile, there is no process for this.

This also applies to any documentation you need to produce as part of the deliverable. In one team I worked in, we had a documentation person preparing docs. In another, we used Sharepoint, in another - another wiki. A few years back, all documentation was delivered as MS word documents or in docbook format. It depends on your circumstances.

Defining what constitutes a deliverable is the purpose of a "definition of done" meeting. In there you can decide, if necessary, where the documentation is to be presented.

Comment: Thanks for this - Re the first part of your answer - how will post live support be able to support the application without written documentation (we are talking a large geographically dispersed corporate here)   RE the second part of my question - I am talking about documenting a new interface between a browser based system and a back end decisioning engine.  My question is what about documenting the functionality for a) testers  b) post live support

Comment: @user3049513 edited. Note that "testers" isn't well defined. If they are part of the team, then the first part of my answer applies (there is no *need* of permanent documentation). If they are part of another team, the second part applies.

Answer (score 0):

1.For example if you use Team Foundation Server (Or Service Cloud version, free for < 5 user), you can store historical discuss about user story (Portal Team Web Access)

2.In agile for example we use User Story in order to specify behavior, but user story can be limited to defnie behavior , so you can also use Use Case in order define your functional need.

You can specify with use case on Scrum, it's not error.